# JavaScript error on custom button

Tags: ajax

I have created a custom button with following Onclick JS Code -

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")} 
var Profile = "{!User.Profile}"; 
var OrderIds = "{! Order.Id }"; 
var OrderStatus = "{!Order.Status}"; 
if(Profile == "System Administrator") { 
if(OrderStatus == "Specific Status"){ 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("OrderLocking","lockOrder", 
{orderId:OrderIds}); 
location.reload(); 
} 
else { 
alert("Only specific Orders can be locked"); 
} 

} 
else { 
alert("You do not have the privileges to lock the order"); 
}
```

This is the class being called -

```
global class Orderlocking{


     webservice static void lockOrder(Id orderId)
     {
      Approval.LockResult lrList = Approval.lock(orderId, false);


    }
}
```

But on clicking the button I'm facing the below error -

> faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'No operation available for
>   request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this:

```
var result = sforce.apex.execute("OrderLocking","lockOrder", 
{orderId:OrderIds});
```

Needs to be

```
var result = sforce.apex.execute("Orderlocking","lockOrder", 
{orderId:OrderIds});
```

Case is important (notice the lowercase l in locking)

Comment: No idea why the makers of Apex decided to go for case insensitivity - it's caused no end of problems a bunch of devs who run into problems the moment they step into another language.